# Android. Close Fragment by calling Method in the Fragment from a Button in the Fragment?

Tags: android, button, fragment

Im new to Android and so far everything went fine. Until i entered the Fragment Terrain. 
In my Application I want a user to click a  button in a activity. With that Button pressed so far i´m opening a fragment in which the user can change Settings. 
Then i want to close, delete, whatever as long as i dont see the fragment anymore, from within the fragment.

So: Activity "A", opens Fragment "a". 
 - do stuff in the Fragment - 
    User, calls Method in "a" by Button, to close "a" .

here is my xml file to the fragment "a":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="145dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#EBDDE2" >

 //took out a seekbar textview and checkbox for now. 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLeaveFragment"
        style="@style/buttonredblack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar_Radius"
        android:onClick="closeFragment"              <--- this i want to call in the fragment. 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/button_ok" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the java file of my fragment "a" activity:

```
  public class SearchingRadiusFragment extends Fragment implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{

        public static String username;

        public void onAttach(Activity activity){
            super.onAttach(activity);
        }

        public void onCeate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setUpLayout();

        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_radius_searching,container, false);
            return view;


        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(bundle != null){
            username = bundle.getString("username", null);
        }
        }



        public void closeFragment(View v){
            ((UserProfileActivity)getActivity()).closeSearchingRadiusFragment(); 
        }

        }
```

now the necessary method in the activity "A":

```
public void closeSearchingRadiusFragment(){
          SearchingRadiusFragment frag = new SearchingRadiusFragment();
          FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,android.R.animator.fade_out);
          transaction.remove(frag);
          transaction.addToBackStack(null);
          transaction.commit();
      }
```

what am i missing? 
eclipse gives me a Illegal.State.Expression. Saying the method closeFragment() could not be found in activity "A". Even though i want to use the one in the fragment "a".

If i change the name of the Method buttonLeaveFragment is calling to: closeSearchingFragment 
Nothing happens, but the app doesn´t crash either.

Comment: Is your setting a new fragment? if so You can replace the fragment or add as a child fragment

Comment: No my settings are in the fragment. I want to change the seekbar and then submit that with the press of ok in "a" and also close "a"

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace your visible fragment "A" with a new fragment (for example "B") using:

```
  transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, fragmentB);
```

On click button try this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,android.R.animator.fade_out);                         
transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, fragmentB);
transaction.commit();
```

Your visible fragmentA will be replace from fragmentB

Comment: Worked smooth. Thank you!

Comment: @user3457769 If this solved your issue, you should accept it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/253846 & Augusto, this is not set to a "best answer" but to "answer which resolved" the solution ;)